# Accumulator using For Loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

My teacher wants a program to ask the user for a positive integer number value, which the program should loop to get the sum of all integers from 1 up to the numbered entered. In For Loop using Python.

Here's what I came up with for the For Loop but it is not's not looping when I type in a negative number and it won't display an answer when I input a positive number after inputting a negative number.

```
x=int(input("Please pick a positive integer"))
sum=0
for i in range(1,x):
    sum=sum+1
    print(sum)
else:
    x=int(input("Please pick a positive integer"))
```

Help?

Comment: For future reference python offers a sum function.  So you could use `sum(range(x+1))` where x is your positive integer value.

Answer (score 3):

How about implementing something like the following. There are a few problems with your program, **most notably**:
**1.** The sum is being repeatedly printed for every value. 
 **2.** You are simply adding 1 to the sum instead of adding the integer `i`. 
 **3.** You are not returning on your function if your user does not enter a positive integer. 
 **4.**  You have no `if` statement for if the integer is greater than 0.

```
def intpicker():
        x=int(input("Please pick a positive integer"))
        sum=0
        if x >= 0:
            for i in range(1,x):
                sum=sum+i
            print(sum)
        else:
            return intpicker()
```

This code could be further abbreviated, but for all intents and purposes you should probably just try and understand this implementation as a start.

Comment: What about exit from recursion? Now it will be forever cycle.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few fatal flaws in your program. See below:

```
x=int(input("Please pick a positive integer")) #what if the user inputs "a"
sum=0
for i in range(1,x): # this will not include the number that they typed in
    sum=sum+1 # you are adding 1, instead of the i
    print(sum) 
else:
    x=int(input("Please pick a positive integer")) # your script ends here without ever using the above variable x
```

This is what I might do:

```
while True: # enters loop so it keeps asking for a new integer
    sum = 0
    x = input("Please pick an integer (type q to exit) > ")
    if x == "q": # ends program if user enters q
        break
    else:
        # try/except loop to see if what they entered is an integer
        try:
            x = int(x)
        except:
            print "You entered {0}, that is not a positive integer.".format(x)
            continue
        for i in range(1, x+1): # if the user enters 2, this will add 1 and 2, instead of 1.
            sum += i 
        print sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=int(input("Please pick a positive integer: "))
total = 0
for num in range (1,x+1):
    total+=num
print(total)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():    
    x=int(input("Please pick a positive integer: "))
    sum=0
    
    if x > 0:
        for i in range(1,x):
            sum=sum+i
        print(sum)
    else:
        print("The integer you entered is not a positive integer.")
        main()
main()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).